# How to do redirect and give an error message after failed put

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class FavoritePhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :photo
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { 
   scope: [:photo_id],
   message: 'can only favorite an item once'
   }
end

PhotosController
def favorite
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  if request.put?
    current_user.favorites << @photo
    redirect_to :back, notice: 'You successfully favorited this photo'
  else request.delete?
    current_user.favorites.delete(@photo)
    redirect_to :back, notice: 'You successfully unfavorited this photo'
  end
end

<%= link_to favorite_photo_path("#{photo.id}"), method: :put do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
<% end %>

resources :photos do
  match :favorite, on: :member, via: [:put, :delete]
end
```

This works in preventing the User from favoriting the same photo more than once and the error message "User can only favorite an item once" shows up in my Heroku log, however, when they attempt to favorite a photo twice there is no redirect and message explaining to the User what has happened, it just times out at favorite_photo_path('#{photo.id}").

Comment: Try `if request.put? and @photo.valid?`

Comment: Can you please edit the code in my controller above I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Oh, that was using `find`. Then that won't work. Sorry for not reading that properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def favorite
    @photo = Photo.find params[:id]
    if request.put?
      response = current_user.favorite_photos.new(photo: @photo)
      if !response.valid?  
       redirect_to :back
       flash[:danger] = "You have already favorited this photo"
      else
       response.save
       redirect_to :back 
       flash[:success] = "You have successfully favorited this photo"
     end
   else request.delete?
     current_user.favorites.delete(@photo)
     redirect_to :back, notice: 'You successfully unfavorited this photo' 
   end 
 end
```

This is the only one I have gotten to work thus far.

Comment: Interesting solution - how come you're not using the ActiveModel error messages?

Comment: for ascetics. the flash[:danger] looks nicer with the color background across the top of the screen. also, the rails error messages are shown inside brackets with quotations. I don't know if you can change how rails error messages are shown?

Comment: Yes it means you have to iterate through them as they are an array. As for the styling, that's a CSS issue and can be applied to both "flash" and "ActiveRecord" errors :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure the best approach is to perform a delete and an update in the same action, but if you'd like to do it this way, you could do something like:

```
User
  has_many :favorite_photos

PhotosController
def favorite
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  if request.put?
    favorite = current_user.favorite_photos.new(photo: @photo)
    if favorite.save
       redirect_to :back, notice: 'You successfully favorited this photo'
    else
       redirect_to photo_path(@photo), notice: favorite.errors.full_messages
    end
  else request.delete?
    current_user.favorites.delete(@photo)
    redirect_to :back, notice: 'You successfully unfavorited this photo'
  end
end
```

Comment: this does not work. it wont allow to favorite photos that have not been favorited. it results in an internal error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're relying on `ActiveRecord` validations to populate your view, when they're separate layers of abstraction.

You will need to include some sort of conditional logic to determine whether the `@photo` passes the validations you've set:

```
#app/controllers/photos_controller.rb
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def favorite
    @photo = Photo.find params[:id]

    response = current_user.favorites << @photo if request.put?
    response = current_user.favorites.delete @photo if request.delete?   

    if response.valid? 
      message = response.errors.full_messages.first
    else
      message = request.put? ? "You have successfully favourited this photo" : "You have successfully unfavourited this photo"
    end
    redirect_to @photo, notice: message
  end
end
```

Comment: this does not work. when i try to favorite a photo that has already been favorited I get the following error message: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: User can only favorite an item once): Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 3.9ms). when i try to favorite a photo that has not been favorited I get the following error message: Completed 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: i figured it out. will post answer later.

Comment: What did you do to get the answer?